# minimization over all probability distributions

Tags: real-analysis, probability, expectation, supremum-and-infimum

Let $$\mathcal{M} \equiv \Bigl\{\text{probability measure } \mu \text{ over } [0,1] \Big| \int_0^1 x \mathrm{d} \mu = 1/2 \Bigr\}.$$ Let $\underline{x} \in (0,1)$ be a fixed number. If $\underline{x} > 1/2$, it is easy to see $$\inf_{\mu \in \mathcal{M}} \int_{\underline{x}}^1 x \mathrm{d} \mu = 0.$$ But what is $$\inf_{\mu \in \mathcal{M}} \int_{\underline{x}}^1 x \mathrm{d} \mu$$ if $\underline{x} < 1/2$?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\int_a^b f(x)\; d\mu(x)$ notation is not good if $\mu$ is a measure that might give 
nonzero mass to one of the endpoints.  It's better to use $\int_A f(x)\; d\mu(x)$ for an integral over the set $A$, or $\int \chi_A(x) f(x)\; d\mu(x)$ where $\chi_A$ is the indicator function of $A$.

In this case, note that $$\chi_{[\underline{x}, 1]}(x) x \ge \frac{x - \underline{x}}{1-\underline{x}} \ \text{for}\ 0 \le x \le 1$$
so that
$$ \int \chi_{[\underline{x}, 1]}(x) x \; d\mu(x) \ge \int \frac{x - \underline{x}}{1-\underline{x}}\; d\mu(x) =  \frac{1/2 - \underline{x}}{1-\underline{x}}$$
and this is best possible, as you see with measures of the form 
$$ \frac{1}{2(1-s)} \delta_s + \frac{1-2s}{2(1-s)} \delta_1 $$
where $0 < s < \underline{x} \le 1/2$, $\delta_x$ being a unit mass at $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much for correcting my notations and giving me this beautiful answer! How did you come up with that particular function? Is it because it is the largest linear function below $\chi_{[\underline{x},1]}(x)$? I'm just wondering if this kind of method can be extended to general nonnegative increasing functions?

Comment: Yes, it's a polynomial of degree $1$ below $x \chi_{[\underline{x},1]}(x)$.

Comment: In general, this is how you get inequalities  of this type: if $f$ and $g$ are Borel measurable functions and $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then $\int_[a,b] f(x) d\mu(x) \le \int_[a,b] g(x) d\mu(x)$ for all Borel probability measures $\mu$ on $[a,b]$.  If, on the other hand, $f(s) > g(s)$ at some point $s$, then there will be a probability measure, namely $\delta_s$, for which $\int f(x) d\mu(x) > \int g(x) d\mu(x)$.